# WPF DataGrid - Disable DataGridCheckBoxColumn

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to use a datagridView to create a multi-check grid.

I have extended the grid and all works fine except that when I check a checkbox in the DataGridCheckBoxColumn, it selects the row. Since I have a lot of loading going on when the selected row changes, this makes quickly selecting checkboxes slow. Is there a way or recommendation to prevent the row from being selected when I select a CheckBox in the checkbox column?
I have already get the other rows of the gridView worked ( when I click on them , they are disabled ) using this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53128529/wpf-datagrid-disable-certain-column-selection) the problem for now is with the DataGridCheckBoxColumn.

**PS:** I'm searching for a solution with DataGridCheckBoxColumn not with CheckBox

What I need exactly is using this `CellStyle="{StaticResource DisableSelection}"` in the DataGridCheckBoxColumn

How can I get that worked?

```
  <DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding GridModel}" x:Name="patientGrid"   VerticalAlignment="Top"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="false" Height="484"  Grid.RowSpan="2" RenderTransformOrigin="0.497,0.551" >
                <DataGrid.Resources>
                    <Style x:Key="DisableSelection" TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/> 
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.Resources>
                <DataGrid.Columns>


                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Choose" x:Name="choose" >

                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                    
                    <Style  TargetType="DataGridCell"  BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
                                <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.Checked" Handler="OnChecked"/>
                                <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.Unchecked" Handler="OnChecked"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />

                            </Style>
                            

                        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource DisableSelection}" Header="nmbr" x:Name="workIdcl" Binding="{Binding ID}" IsReadOnly="True"  />
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`, the cell is actually selected before the `CheckBox` is checked.

You could replace the `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` with a `DataGridTemplateColumn` and handle the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event for the `CheckBox`:

```
private void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)sender;
    checkBox.IsChecked = !checkBox.IsChecked.HasValue || !checkBox.IsChecked.Value;
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Choose" x:Name="choose">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style  TargetType="DataGridCell"  BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
                      Checked="OnChecked"
                      Unchecked="OnUnchecked"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Sorry but I need to use DataGridCheckBoxColumn instead of CheckBox

Comment: @abdou_dev: Why? Then you can't customize the `CheckBox`. Unless you create a custom `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` of course. Why do you need a `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`?